# Calculating the next time to run a task, based on a Day and a Time

Tags: c#, .net

I have a rather specific problem working out the best way to calculate the next time a "task" in my program should run, based on the configuration of that task.

Starting with the definition of some things that come through to configure this "Task". First off, an enumeration which looks much like the framework's `DayOfWeek` enum, which I have called `DaysOfWeek` and marked it up with the `FlagsAttribute` to indicate it can be a multiple thereof:

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64
}
```

Secondly the class in question with the appropriate properties, and the method im trying to implement:

```
public class WeeklySchedule 
{

    public DaysOfWeek DaysToRun { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeToRun{ get; set; }

    public override DateTime CalculateNextRunTime(DateTime lastRun)
    {
        // Here's what im trying to implement   
    }
}
```

The requirements *should be* pretty obvious

- If DaysToRun is today, but TimeToRun has already gone today, return the next time/day
- If today is not included in DaysToRun, then find the next day/time to run

Im obviously just having a brain-fart-monday because I cant work out an efficient way to calculate this, short of `ShouldExecuteToday()` method, followed by `FindNextExecutionDay()` and so on (maybe this is the right way.....)

**Edit**: Ok the weekend brain-fog is lifting, here's where Im at so far. If anyone can improve on this it would be appreciated:

First off, ive put a mapping of the two enums into a static member of my class, I know I could Parse from one to the other as per @DorCohen's example, but this makes me feel icky.

```
private static Dictionary<DayOfWeek, DaysOfWeek> DayToDaysMap 
 = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, DaysOfWeek>()
{
{DayOfWeek.Monday, DaysOfWeek.Monday},
{DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DaysOfWeek.Tuesday},
{DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DaysOfWeek.Wednesday},
{DayOfWeek.Thursday, DaysOfWeek.Thursday},
{DayOfWeek.Friday, DaysOfWeek.Friday},
{DayOfWeek.Saturday, DaysOfWeek.Saturday},
{DayOfWeek.Sunday, DaysOfWeek.Sunday},
};
```

Then this method to determine if it should be run on a day:

```
private bool ShouldRunOn(DateTime now)
{
    var days = DayToDaysMap[now.DayOfWeek];
    // If the schedule is not set for the specified day, return false
    if (!this.DaysToRun.HasFlag(days))
        return false;

    // Schedule should run on specified day, just determine if it is in the past
    return this.TimeOfDay > now.TimeOfDay;    
}
```

Then the implementation becomes; "can I run today" and if not "advance up to 6 days and see if I can run that day". Note that the parameter `lastRun` is not used in this implementation, it's used for others (such as a repeating schedule).

```
public override DateTime CalculateNextRunTime(DateTime lastRun)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    if (ShouldRunOn(now))
        return new DateTime(now.Year,now.Month,now.Day,this.TimeOfDay.Hours,
              this.TimeOfDay.Minutes,this.TimeOfDay.Seconds);

    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        now = now.AddDays(1).Date;
        if(ShouldRunOn(now))
            return new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 
              this.TimeOfDay.Hours, this.TimeOfDay.Minutes, this.TimeOfDay.Seconds);
    }
    return DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Improvements welcomed!

Comment: You could take a look at [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) by famous [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: In the `CalculateNextRunTime` function at the end you are repeating a fair bit of code that looks like it could be rolled into the loop to start at 0. You might need to slightly change stuff such as perhaps generating the potential run times for each day and then seeing if they are in the future or not (this will then work the same if the potential date is today or in the future). You could probably also work out the next day without a loop using some kind of bitshifting and logarithm stuff but that is probably a bit too complicated to be worth it to avoid a 7 iteration loop. ;-)

Comment: @Chris - I also think the first iteration could be rolled into the loop, but thats almost the crux of the problem; It could be scheduled today, but earlier on in the day in which case that time should not be returned. Note how the loop bases the time back to midnight using `.Date` which the "today" portion cant do.

Comment: @JamieC: I had noticed that. I've put an answer down now that does the loop slightly differently. I think it is much neater code though may do a few more unnecessary checks than your code. If you want readability though which I'm guessing you do then this should work. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rewrite from me:

```
public DateTime CalculateNextRunTime()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    for (var i = 0; i<=7; i++)
    {
        var potentialRunTime = now.AddDays(i);
        if (!DateInDayOfWeek(potentialRunTime))
            continue;
        potentialRunTime = potentialRunTime.Date + TimeToRun;
        if (potentialRunTime < DateTime.Now)
            continue;
        return potentialRunTime;
    }
    return DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

The rough logic is:

For each day starting from today:
-Check if day is valid, if not skip to next day
-Create the runtime for the day
-Check if the runtime is in the past, if it is skip to next day else return this runtime.

The checking if it is in the past is obviously superfluous for all loops after the first but it is neater to do it for all loops and I doubt the extra comparison is likely to be a bottleneck. :)

`DateInDayOfWeek` in the above is just a method that returns true if the passed day matches one of the days of week held in the `DaysToRun` property. I couldn't use hasFlags since I wasn't using .NET 4 in writing my test code. You might want to keep it as a separate method though to avoid it getting cluttered. ;-)

Comment: I prefer the look of this code for sure. Im going to plug it in and run it through all my unit tests to check the logic doesnt differ from mine. As long as it passes this is the accepted answer :)

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for your help Chris.

Comment: No problem. I couldn't quite put my finger on what to do to improve your code so thought rewriting it would be easier. I guess in many ways it was about rethinking how the criteria work (ie that it always has to be ahead of now so you can do the same check for if its today than if its yesterday and so on.

Answer (score 0):

in both of else statements you need to return the next day to run the task, 
you can do it by simple loop.

```
        DaysOfWeek DaysToRun = DaysOfWeek.Friday | DaysOfWeek.Monday;
        TimeSpan timeToRun = new TimeSpan(12,0,0);

        DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
        DaysOfWeek Day = (DaysOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DaysOfWeek), now.DayOfWeek.ToString());
        if (DaysToRun.HasFlag(Day))
        {
            if (now.TimeOfDay < timeToRun )
            {
                MessageBox.Show(nowTime.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                //return next day
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //return next day
        }
```

Comment: This is a good start, but a couple of points. 1) `now.TimeOfDay` will get you a `TimeSpan` so no need to create one. 2) I dont see this cycling for the next available day to run.

Comment: I disagree that it's "a simple loop", At it's simplest it's a loop as per my edit above, but thats not that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bitwise to collect weekdays or month days.

Here are the bitwise values for weekdays:

```
2   Sunday 
4   Monday 
8   Tuesday 
16  Wednesday 
32  Thursday 
64  Friday 
128 Saturday
```

If you need to calculate the next run date for Monday, Thursday and Saturday then you'll need to sum 4, 32 and 128 and pass the result value as a collection day.

Example: (4 + 32 + 128) = 164

You will use the same method as a collection day for month days.

Here are the bitwise values for month days, from day 1 to 31:

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
2147483648
```

Here is the function:

```
static DateTime GetNextRun(int hour, int min, bool isDaily, bool isWeekly, bool isMonthly, bool isLastDayOfMonth, int collectionDay)
        {
            var today = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, hour, min, 0, 0);
            var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);

            if (isDaily)
            {
                return tomorrow;
            }
            else if (isWeekly)
            {
                if (collectionDay < 2)
                {
                    throw new Exception("The collection Day is invalid.");
                }

                if (collectionDay > 255)
                {
                    throw new Exception("The collection Day is invalid.");
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    var dayOfWeek = (int)today.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek;
                    var power = (int)(Math.Pow(2, dayOfWeek + 1));
                    if ((power & collectionDay) > 0)
                    {
                        return today.AddDays(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (isMonthly)
            {
                var nextDate = tomorrow;

                if (collectionDay < 2 && isLastDayOfMonth)
                {
                    return new DateTime(tomorrow.Year, tomorrow.Month, GetDaysInMonth(tomorrow), hour, min, 0, 0);
                }

                if (collectionDay < 2)
                {
                    throw new Exception("The collection Day is invalid.");
                }

                while (true)
                {
                    var power = (int)(Math.Pow(2, nextDate.Day));
                    if ((power & collectionDay) > 0)
                    {
                        if (isLastDayOfMonth && nextDate.Month != tomorrow.Month)
                        {
                            return new DateTime(tomorrow.Year, tomorrow.Month, GetDaysInMonth(tomorrow), hour, min, 0, 0);
                        }

                        return nextDate;
                    }

                    nextDate = nextDate.AddDays(1);
                }
            }

            return DateTime.MaxValue;
        }

        static int GetDaysInMonth(DateTime d)
        {
            for (int i = 28; i < 33; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, i, 1, 1, 0, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return (i - 1);
                }
            }

            return 31;
        }
```

How to use:

To get the next Monday:

```
var d = GetNextRun(16, 13, false, true, false, false, 2);
```

To get the next Monday or Thursday or Saturday "(4 + 32 + 128) = 164":

```
var d = GetNextRun(16, 13, false, true, false, false, 164);
```

To get the next second days of a month:

```
var d = GetNextRun(16, 13, false, false, true, false, 4);
```

To get the next 2 or 5 or 7 days of a month "(4 + 32 + 128) = 164":

```
var d = GetNextRun(16, 13, false, false, true, false, 164);
```

Also you can set the isLastDayOfMonth flag to calculate the last day of month for the next run.