# Calculate next run date for schedule using C#

Tags: c#, datetime

My web application inserts the schedule details of reports in Table 1. Schedule details are exactly like in Task Schedular.

1. One Time ()
2. Daily (Recur)
3. Weekly (Recur, Sun, Mon, Tues, Wed,Thurs, Fri, Sat)
4. Monthly (All months. Days or On (First, Second, Third, Fourth and Last), (Sun, Mon, Tues, Wed,Thurs, Fri, Sat) )

I am planning to create a batch process, which

1. calculate the next run date for each report and update the column in Table 1.
2. should pickup the reports that need to be run tonight.

I don't need to create any trigger in task scheduler. All I need is to calculate the next run date for a report, based on the report has been set to schedule.

Any help would be great.I need

My attempt:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum DaysOfWeek
    {
        Sunday = 1,
        Monday = 2,
        Tuesday = 4,
        Wednesday = 8,
        Thursday = 16,
        Friday = 32,
        Saturday = 64
    }

 private void CalculateNextRunTime()
 {
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime nextRun; 
    DateTime dtStart = DateTime.ParseExact("01/05/2014", "mm/dd/yyyy", provider);
    DateTime dtLastRun = DateTime.ParseExact("01/06/2014", "mm/dd/yyyy", provider);;
    int recurNo = 2;
    string recurFrequency = "Monday|Wednesday|Friday";
    DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.ParseExact("01/06/2015", "mm/dd/yyyy", provider);

    //store the weekdays in an array
    ArrayList weekList = new ArrayList();
    string[] weekDays = recurFrequency.Split('|');
    foreach (string weekDay in weekDays)
        weekList.Add(weekDay);

    DateTime now;
    if (dtLastRun != null)
        now = dtLastRun;
    else
        now = dtStart;


    DaysOfWeek DaysToRun = DaysOfWeek.Monday | DaysOfWeek.Wednesday | DaysOfWeek.Friday;        
    DaysOfWeek Day = (DaysOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DaysOfWeek), now.DayOfWeek.ToString());
    if (DaysToRun.HasFlag(Day))
    {
        // get  next run date (should be Wednesday 01/08/2014) 
        if (dtLastRun.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
           nextRun = dtLastRun.AddDays(2);               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am storing the week days to run in string. Based on it I need to calculate the next run date for given start date or last run date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565703/calculating-the-next-time-to-run-a-task-based-on-a-day-and-a-time/58762204#58762204

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you want to create a batch process on web application in order to update report times. However you can't do that without any external application because web application action will work as the request comes. One option may be you might keep your web browser open and create an ajax request that periodically calls `UpdateRecords()` or something like it.

Comment: Yes. I am planning to create a batch process that runs daily and that picks up the records of next Run Date equals to today().